# Analytics on GitHub pages

Tags: github, analytics, github-pages

Does GitHub provide some (native) way to track visitors on some hosted page (pages at *.github.io/project)?

I know we can see traffic on GitHub repositories and I thought there would be some similar features for pages but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 38):

No.

The only way to track analytics for a GitHub Pages page/site is via a third-party service such as [Clicky](https://clicky.com), [Google Analytics](https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/analytics/), [Gauges](https://get.gaug.es), [Plausible](https://plausible.io), etc.

Comment: Not looking to shoot the messenger or anything, but... This sucks. I don't want to spend money on a Github Paes site, that's why I'm using Github Pages. And I don't want to hand the data over to Google, because why would I want to do that?

Comment: Mixpanel has a free tier, and Matomo is a privacy-friendly alternative to GA

Comment: I went with [Plausible](https://plausible.io/plausible.io), it's open source.

Answer (score 10):

GitHub has provided native "[GitHub Traffic Analytics](https://github.com/blog/1672-introducing-github-traffic-analytics)" since 2014.

Besides tracking visitors to your repository, it provides a 'content' panel where you can see the traffic to individual pages within that repository.

1. Navigate to your desired repository
2. Go to 'Insights' and select 'Traffic'.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

If your GitHub page doesn't have enough traffic, or it's new, you'll see this:

[image]

Comment: I'm not certain, but I believe this is a graph of visits to individual pages in your GitHub repo via github.com URLs. Not the hosted GitHub Pages URLs.

Comment: This answer is for GitHub repo. Not GitHub pages. For GitHub pages, I think Google Analytics is fine.

Comment: yeah, but at some point [google analytics is becoming evil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_be_evil) to my opinion. Too much tracking :-\

Comment: In that case you might consider building your own Matomo (https://matomo.org) instance.

Answer (score 4):

Such a feature does not exist yet natively in GitHub. If it does, it is not mentioned in the documentation either at [Viewing traffic to a repository](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/viewing-activity-and-data-for-your-repository/viewing-traffic-to-a-repository), or at [About GitHub Pages](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages).

They do collect data though, as per the Data Collection section at *About GitHub Pages*:

> When a GitHub Pages site is visited, the visitor's IP address is logged and stored for security purposes, regardless of whether the visitor has signed into GitHub or not. For more information about GitHub's security practices, see GitHub Privacy Statement.

There are currently at least two GitHub Community discussion entries for this topic, marked as product feedback. Consider voting them up to increase the chance that this feature will be eventually implemented:

- https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/31474
- https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/48900

Note that the *Traffic* feature is not available on GitHub Enterprise (GHE). If you are interested in this feature, plus Analytics for GH Pages for GHE, I suggest raising this to the team in your organization that is responsible for your GHE account.